# Can a useful engine make use of an isothermal process?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

This is a purely hypothetical question, but I was wondering whether its possible to design a useful engine which makes use of both an isothermal process and a piston. Thinking about this, the issue that I came across was that in order to perform an isothermal process, we must have $PV = constant$. Now, we will need the volume of the gas inside the piston to increase as we add some heat to the gas inside the piston, so that the piston does some work. Therefore, we will need the pressure of the gas inside the piston to decrease, so that the the process is isothermal. But in order for the pressure inside the piston to decrease while the gas inside the piston expands isothermally, *we* will need to do some work; for example, since the pressure of the gas inside the piston will be the same as the pressure of the air outside the piston, we might decrease the pressure of the air surrounding the piston (we could do this if we placed the piston in some kind of closed chamber, for example). But the issue is that since decreasing this pressure will require us to do work, it is not clear that any process that utilizes this process will do net work for us.

On the other hand, if we start off with a low pressure in the hypothetical chamber above, a large change in volume of the gas in the piston will require only a small change in the pressure of the gas in the chamber (where again, this pressure equals the pressure inside the piston) in order to preserve the isothermal nature of the process (this can be seen from the hyperbolic nature of the relationship between P and V). Changing the pressure of the chamber slightly ought to require minimal work. So maybe if the initial pressure of the chamber is low enough, we could still get a net amount of work out of some cycle that utilizes our isothermal process? In this case, how would we implement the pressure change in the chamber tho?

Also: Are there any real engines that utilize isothermal processes like this?

Answer (score 1):

The key word in the question is "useful".  For an engine to be useful, it should be able to generate a specified power, where power is the amount of work done per unit time.  Since isothermal processes necessarily have to transfer heat in order to hold a constant temperature, the rate at which those processes can transfer heat becomes a limiting factor.  If you are interested in a "slow" process with low power generation, this may not be a problem.  However, for something like the engine in an automobile, the power requirement is very high, and there isn't time for enough heat transfer to take place inside the engine's cylinders to maintain isothermal conditions AND provide the power required to make that engine "useful".

Answer (score 0):

I’ll answer the last question first.

The process you are describing is a reversible isothermal process in which the temperature of the gas is constant and the difference between the temperature of the gas and the temperature of the surroundings is infinitely small so that they can be considered in thermal equilibrium. In order for the process to be reversible, it must be carried out quasi-statically, that is, extremely slowly.  Because rate of the process is extremely low, the rate of producing work (engine power) would be too low to be practical.. As someone once said, if you put a Carnot heat engine in your car you would get phenomenal fuel economy but pedestrians would be passing you by!

Your assumption that in order to have a reversible isothermal process it requires work to adjust the gas pressure and that work negates the work done by the gas, is incorrect. One can imagine gradually reducing the external pressure allowing the gas to gradually expand theoretically doing little or no work. Consider the following thought experiment. (See diagrams below).

Let's say you have the gas in a vertically oriented frictionless cylinder and piston. On top of the piston you have weight consisting of grains of sand which, in addition to the external air pressure, provides the external pressure on the system. You now slide a grain of sand horizontally off of a platform connected to the shaft of the piston and onto another platform along side the cylinder. That reduces the external pressure allowing the gas to expand and perform work in raising the remaining weight. Sliding each grain of sand horizontally off the piston in the absence of any friction would theoretically involve no work, other than to get an extremely small mass moving. Whatever work there is would be extremely small compared to the work done by the gas.

We remove the sand one grain at a time causing an infinitely small reduction in external pressure. That results in an infinitely small expansion of the gas, $Adh$. The expansion causes an infinitely small decrease in the gas temperature $dT$ and infinitely small transfer of heat $dQ$ into the gas to bring its temperature and pressure back into equilibrium with surroundings, awaiting the next removal of a weight.

For the process to be reversible we need to be able to return both the system and surroundings to their original state. To do this we need to raise the first weight that was transferred to the surroundings and place it on top to reverse the process.  This alters the surroundings by the work done to raise the single grain of sand. This demonstrates that in order for the process to be reversible the weights must be infinitesimally small.

Hope this helps.

[image]